# mysql ranking on sum and best score

Tags: mysql

i have a table with this structure:

```
score_id | user_id | category | subcategory | score
1        | 1       | game     | 0           | 100
2        | 1       | game     | 0           | 200
3        | 1       | quiz     | 0           | 2000
4        | 1       | quiz     | 1           | 1000
5        | 1       | game     | 0           | 10
6        | 1       | game     | 1           | 10
7        | 1       | game     | 2           | 100
8        | 1       | game     | 1           | 500
9        | 2       | game     | 0           | 600
```

and i need different query mysql:

1) ranking of all team grouped by user_id sum of all best result beetween all records of user for category and subcategory

expected result

```
user_id | total_score | ranking
1       | 3310        | 1
2       | 600         | 2
```

where

```
3310 = (200 + 10 + 100+1000+2000) 
 200 is the best result of game 0, 
 10 is the best result of game 1, 
 100 is the best result of game 2, 
 2000 is the best result of quiz 0
 1000 is the best result of quiz 1

600 = (600)
 600 is the best result of game 0,
```

---

SOLUTION by @Strawberry (thank you)

```
SELECT a.*
     , @i:=@i+1 rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , SUM(subtotal) total 
         FROM 
           ( SELECT user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
                   , MAX(score) subtotal 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
            ) x 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY total DESC;
```

---

2) ranking of all team grouped by user_id sum of all best result beetween all records of user for category and subcategory for only game or quiz

expected result game

```
user_id | total_score | ranking
2       | 600         | 1
1       | 310         | 2
```

where

```
600 = (600)
 600 is the best result of game 0, 

310 = (200 + 10 + 100) 
 200 is the best result of game 0, 
 10 is the best result of game 1, 
 100 is the best result of game 2,
```

expected result quiz

```
user_id | total_score | ranking
1       | 3000       | 1
2       | 0          | 2
```

where

```
3000 = (200 + 10 + 100) 
 2000 is the best result of quiz 0
 1000 is the best result of quiz 1

 0= (0)
(user_id= 2 don't play quiz)
```

---

BASED ON SOLUTION by @Strawberry (thank you)

```
SELECT a.*
     , @i:=@i+1 rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , SUM(subtotal) total 
         FROM 
           ( SELECT user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
                   , MAX(score) subtotal 
                FROM my_table
                WHERE category = 'game' // or 'quiz
               GROUP 
                  BY user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
            ) x 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY total DESC;
```

---

3) ranking of all team grouped by user_id sum of all best result beetween all records of user for category and subcategory for only game or quiz with specific subcategory

expected result game 0

```
user_id | total_score | ranking
2       | 600         | 1
1       | 310         | 2
```

where

```
600 = (600)
 600 is the best result of game 0, 

200 = (200 ) 
 200 is the best result of game 0,
```

---

BASED ON SOLUTION by @Strawberry (thank you)

```
SELECT a.*
     , @i:=@i+1 rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , SUM(subtotal) total 
         FROM 
           ( SELECT user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
                   , MAX(score) subtotal 
                FROM my_table
                WHERE category = 'game'
                AND subcategory = '0'
               GROUP 
                  BY user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
            ) x 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY total DESC;
```

---

4) get total score of single  user (ex user_id=1 ) for query 1

5) get ranking of single user (ex user_id=1 ) for query 1

6) get total score of single  user (ex user_id=1 ) for query 2

7) get ranking of single user (ex user_id=1 ) for query 2

8) get total score of single  user (ex user_id=1 ) for query 3

9) get ranking of single user (ex user_id=1 ) for query 3

thank you!

Comment: You've got some attemps of doing all of this or you just want somebody to write it for you ?

Comment: As written, I think this question is too broad.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another question about one of the themes.

Comment: @pierregrander , i need a hint, i found a solution for get best value, without sum

Comment: @gordonlinoff i think the same, but maybe one query can be correlate to another... so i decided to group everything. Offcourse is very appreciate any partial help :)

Comment: "1) ranking of all team grouped by user_id sum of all best result between all records of user for category and subcategory" This is not intelligible.

Comment: @Strawberry ehm sorry for by poor english... i need ranking of all user, with only the best score for each category and subcategory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first one. Using this, show us your best efforts for the remainder...

```
SELECT a.*
     , @i:=@i+1 rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , SUM(subtotal) total 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
                   , MAX(score) subtotal 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY user_id
                   , category
                   , subcategory
            ) x 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY total DESC;
```

Note that this solution doesn't account for ties.

Comment: it works, thank you! i just edit a where condition for get point 2 and 3